# installation of perception_pcl_electric_unstable

Tags: pcl, pcl-ros

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Recently I am dealing with surface reconstruction using pcl, and I need the OctreePointCloudSearch class under pcl::octree. But the default pcl version under perception_pcl is only 1.1, and classes like OctreePointCloudSearch are missing in this version.

So following the discussion from this thread,
http://answers.ros.org/question/11622/how-do-you-upgrade-pcl-to-the-current-release
I download perception_pcl_electric_unstable from
http://svn.pointclouds.org/ros/trunk/perception_pcl_electric_unstable/
and rosmake it. Unfortunately I have no idea how to get rid of the following error,
"......
/usr/bin/ld: cannot find -lpcl_range_image_border_extractor
collect2: ld returned 1 exit status
make[3]: *** [../bin/convert_pcd_to_image] Error 1
make[3]: Leaving directory `/home/robot/ros/perception_pcl/pcl_ros/build'
......"

My current setting: ubuntu 11.04 + ros electric

You advice is greatly appreciated.

clark

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/29839/installation-of-perception_pcl_electric_unstable/) by [clark](https://answers.ros.org/users/401/clark/) on ROS Answers with karma: 393 on 2012-03-15

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [karthik](https://answers.ros.org/users/961/karthik/) on 2012-03-19**:
Hey i noticed that you haven't set your ros path for this unstable version before compiling it. I see "/home/robot/ros/perception_pcl/pcl_ros/build" in your error which is not unstable version. I have recently updated my unstable version in similar environment and it works fine

**Comment by [karthik](https://answers.ros.org/users/961/karthik/) on 2012-03-19**:
I even had a bug in flann and reported the solution to the developer which was updated instantaneously.  Could you do "svn info" and tell the version you checked out.

**Comment by [clark](https://answers.ros.org/users/401/clark/) on 2012-03-20**:
Karthik, the reason that the folder name is shown as perception_pcl rather than "perception_pcl_electric_unstable" just because I changed the folder name after svn the source. BTW, svn info gives "Revision: 241"

**Comment by [karthik](https://answers.ros.org/users/961/karthik/) on 2012-03-20**:
Clark: I have answered your question. I tried it on other system n was able to recreate your issue, I was able to solve it in the explained fashion.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hello!

A colleague of mine had the same problem some days ago. You need to
remove the compiler libary flag "-lpcl_range_image_border_extractor" in the manifest.xml.  That library doesnt exist anymore because it was merged with another one. :) Then it should compile properly.

Greets,
Robert

http://svn.pointclouds.org/ros/trunk/perception_pcl_electric_unstable/pcl/manifest.xml

---

Originally posted by [einrob](https://answers.ros.org/users/1988/einrob/) with karma: 16 on 2012-03-16

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [clark](https://answers.ros.org/users/401/clark/) on 2012-03-18**:
thank u for the advice.